# What does CosmosDB option "production" vs "non-production" really do?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azureportal

When you create CosmosDB account in Azure Portal you are provided the choice of "Account Type", with options:

- *Production*
- *Non-Production*

The info button in creation wizard in portal just mentions:

> Controls UI experience offered in the portal and Cosmos Explorer. Does not impact runtime behavior of the service. Can be changed later.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-database-account) does is just as vague:

> This is an Azure resource tag setting that tunes the Portal experience but does not affect the underlying Azure Cosmos DB account. You can change this value anytime.

**What exactly are those "tuned" UI experience differences?** No notable differences catch my eye, nor can I find this setting anywhere after creation, nor do I see a way to change this later..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks there are not some obvious differences, if you select the `Production/Non-Production` when creating the account, it will enable/disable `Geo-Redundancy` and `Multi-region Writes` for you automatically, but you can still set them manually.

When you creating two accounts that just have different account types, the difference in the portal is the tag named `CosmosAccountType`, it will be `Production` or `Non-Production`, this is the value you can change anytime mentioned in the doc.

Actually, don't worry about this, just select the corresponding type depends on the actual scenario e.g. production or non-production, because it will not affect the underlying Cosmos DB account.

[image]

Comment: Curious. If it is so, then can't see such minor thing (which would be even more moot when deploying using ARM templates) pass in a design meeting to be implemented at all ;) Smells like "for historic reasons".

Comment: @ImrePühvel Yes, you can even remove this tag, it will not cause some differences, looks like it is just a tag as mentioned in the doc `This is an Azure resource tag setting`.